# CGContextDrawImage without Transaction animation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-animation, calayer

How do I draw a layer without a transaction animation? For example, when I set the contents of a layer using `CATransaction` it works well:

```
[CATransaction begin];
[CATransaction setValue:(id)kCFBooleanTrue
                 forKey:kCATransactionDisableActions];
myLayer.contents = (id)[[imagesTop objectAtIndex:Number]CGImage];
[CATransaction commit];
```

but I need to change contents from the delegate method `[myLayer setNeedsDisplay]`. Here is the code:

```
-(void)drawLayer:(CALayer *)layer inContext:(CGContextRef)context
{
    CGContextDrawImage(context, rect, Image.CGImage]);    
}
```

Comment: What is the delegate of your layer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CALayer` implements `setNeedsDisplay` method:

> Calling this method will cause the receiver to recache its content. This will result in the layer receiving a `drawInContext:` which may result in the delegate receiving either a `displayLayer:` or `drawLayer:inContext:` message.

... and `displayIfNeeded`:

> When this message is received the layer will invoke `display` if it has been marked as requiring display.

If you wrap `[myLayer displayIfNeeded]` in a `CATransaction`, you can turn off implicit animation.

Comment: sorry but i need to force th redraw,not only if needed

Comment: First you mark the layer as needing re-drawing (`[myLayer setNeedsDisplay]`). Then you tell it to redraw if needed (`[myLayer displayIfNeeded]`). Since you've already marked the layer as needing re-drawing, it will redraw immediately. See the documentation for `displayIfNeeded`, quoted above.

Answer (score 1):

You can subclass `CALayer` and override `actionForKey:`,

```
- (id <CAAction>) actionForKey: (NSString *) key
{
    if ([key isEqualToString: @"contents"])
        return nil;
    return [super actionForKey: key];
}
```

This code disables the built-in animation for the `contents` property.

Alternatively, you can achieve the same effect by implementing the layer's delegate method

```
- (id <CAAction>) actionForLayer: (CALayer *) layer forKey: (NSString *) key
{
    if (layer == myLayer) {
        if ([key isEqualToString: @"contents"])
            return nil;
        return [[layer class] defaultActionForKey: key];
    }
    return [layer actionForKey: key];
}
```